# issues while writing a shell in c

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork

I'm trying to write a shell program in c.
The program needs to have multiple processes created by fork function and be able to print multiple output line in one command. 
For example, like linux terminal, if input is "ls ; ps ; pwd ;", the output should be like this.

```
$./shell
shell> ls ; ps ; pwd ;
(ls output)
(ps output)
(pwd output)
```

And it should be able to open a file and display the command list and the output that file contains.(batch mode I guess?)

Let's say these command lists are in the batch file.

```
batch
1 ls 
2 ps
3 ls ; pwd ; ps
```

And the output is

```
$./shell batch
shell> ls
shell> (ls output)
shell> ps
shell> (ps output)
shell> ls ; pwd ; ps
shell> (ls output)
(ps output)
(pwd output)
```

Here's the code I wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void command(char* myargs[][10], char* buffer);
int tokenizing(char* myargs[][10], char* buffer);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int fd;
    char buffer[200];
    char* myargs[10][10];
    char* token;

    if(argc >= 2) {
        if((fd=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1)
            printf("cannot open file\n");
        else {
            read(fd, buffer, 200);
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            token = strtok(buffer, "\n");
            while(token != NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", token);
                command(myargs, token);
                token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }



    while(1) {
        printf("prompt> ");
        if(fgets(buffer, 200, stdin) == NULL||
                strcmp(buffer, "quit\n") == 0)
            break;
        command(myargs, buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}

void command(char* myargs[][10], char* buffer) {

    int rc = fork();

    if(rc < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
    } else if(rc == 0) {

        int n = tokenizing(myargs, buffer);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {

            int rc2 = fork();
            if(rc2 < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "for failed\n");
            } else if(rc2 == 0) {
                execvp(myargs[i][0], myargs[i]);
                printf("%s: command not found\n", myargs[i][0]);
                exit(0);
            } else {
                wait(NULL);
            }
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else {

        wait(NULL);


    }
}

int tokenizing(char* myargs[][10], char* buffer) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    char* token;
    char* subCommand[10];

    token = strtok(buffer, ";\n");

    while(token != NULL) {
        subCommand[k] = token;
        k++;
        token = strtok(NULL, ";\n");
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        token = strtok(subCommand[i], " \n");
        while(token != NULL) {
            myargs[i][j] = token;
            j++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
        myargs[i][j] = NULL;
        j=0;
    }
}
```

This code works fine but has some issues. When this code runs with a batch file, I struggle with some errors.

[image]

When the program is executed, I think the output should be like the above image file - as far as I know.

[image]

But frequently the program comes out with some weird command line that I didn't even type. These results just happen alternatively.

In addition, if you see 'ps' lists, you can see two shell programs are running.

Can you guys please help me solve these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'strings' in C need a NUL terminator.  Calling strng functions like printf("%s....") and strtok() on char arrays that are not securely NUL-terminated results in undefined behaviour.

read() returns a value.  You can use it to load a terminator into 'buffer'.  To be super-safe, you should attempt to read only [buffer size -1] chars to ensure that there will always be enough space for the terminator, eg:

```
buffer[read(fd, buffer, 199)]='\0';
```

Comment: To be  super-safe, better to inspect the `read()` return value, to see if it is negative, before using it as an index.